# Merge route segments and branches into a single one

Tags: qgis, merge

I have a very long shapefile with many public transport routes (I'm working with QGIS3 on Linux). Many of them are branches or parts of the same route but I don't know which is which, all their common feature is the name of the route, this is an screenshot of attribute table (it's in Spanish):

[image]

My problem is, there are many of them; the most obvious solution is to filter by route and then look each one of them on map to be sure they are not the same, and then use dissolve to merge them into one. As you can see, this is a very time consumig job, is there an easier and faster way?

The desired output is only one entry per route, and highlighted (on map) those who are the same, so that i can decide what to do with it

Comment: Have you tried to dissolve to merge to see what the result is? If a specific route shares a unique value/attribute, the result should be correct.

Comment: Is there a way to do it as you say? I mean merge and qgis finding values/attributes in common. I was trying to avoid doing it manually, but so far that's the way to do it.

Comment: I posted an answer to your question ( if i understood you correctly).

Comment: Not sure if I undestood the question... maybe something similar as this? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/443976/automatically-delete-side-branches-from-a-multipart-linestring-in-qgis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform a merge operation using the **Dissolve algorithm**. Navigate through the top menu from **Vector -> Geoprocessing Tools -> Dissolve**. I am using QGIS 3.10.12. This would open the Dissolve tool. Choose the required layer in the input field, in the optional field you can specify the column in the attribute table that contains the value which is unique for each route. You can enter a name for the result.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I have used dissolve, I think I didn't explained myself. I have about 160 paths, and they all form branches, and there are about 100 routes, so I'm in the order of thousands of paths to look at. What I would like for qgis to do it would be like: take these 160 paths and find those who most likely are from the same branch, group them and then let me visualize them so I can decide what to do (right now I have to go by pairs, then visualizing them, and if they belong to same branch then dissolve them, and so on). So I was wondering if it would be possible to do it "massively"

Comment: Okay. The first thing is to determine the basis of the relationship of the root and branch  segments. How do you define this ->  find those who most likely are from the same branch, group them. This can be done either by using an attribute value or setting some form of spatial relationship. What criteria are you using manually to determine the root and branch segments that belong together?

Comment: Sorry, after a really long time i ended up doing it by hand, it took me a long time. The criteria was in a table which had information on the route, it could say that belongs to the same route or it has the same streets.