Removing end vertices of a line vector in QGIS
I have a line layer in QGIS that I have digitized on the basis of a PNG file. This layer includes main lines and many secondary lines. I would like to remove these secondary lines automatically and not manually, as there are a lot of them. In most cases, these secondary lines only have one vertex and are then connected to the main line. Is there a way to remove the secondary lines? For example, by removing all end vertices of the vector?


Is it somehow possible to share data in this forum?

I've updated the question with my data

Maybe try using network tools to identify the main line. Something similar like here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/418644/88814 or https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/444603/88814

I tried Shortest path (layer to point) but that doesn't work because I have multiple parallel lines and I want to keep these Lines. v.generalize only returns an empty result. I will try the approaches in your second suggestion

Not sure what format your data is in - check Settings -> Data Sources, and select Copy Features as Plain Text, WKT Geometry

What should I do afterwards?

One option would be to use an expression to select the features to be deleted (Select by Expression).
overlay_intersects will get the list of features intersecting, and array_length will get the count of these.
num_points will get the total number of points.
If the ratio of these is <=0.5 then it should meet your secondary point criterion (one intersecting point, and other point(s) not intersecting). Any main lines should fail this criterion.
array_length(overlay_intersects(@layer,@feature))/num_points(@geometry)<=0.5

Obviously this assumes that your segments are actually intersecting as the image indicates!

If I adopt your code in this way, unfortunately only small stand-alone features are selected where no intersections exist. The small features on the main lines unfortunately remain untouched :/

You'll need to share a sample of your data, or otherwise provide more detail about the main lines/secondary lines.
