Curved labeling of rivers in QGIS doesn't always work
I need to label some rivers using curved placement. Sometimes the labels appear, sometimes they do not. I'm sure part of my problem comes from the rivers being divided up into short sections as independent features, with eighty two (82) fields of meta data, in addition to the id and geometry fields. There can ge as many as nine hundred (900) features for one river in my area of study. (The Mississippi River is divided into 2,278 features!)
I have attempted to combine the rivers into single features using the "Multipart to singleparts" and the "Merge lines" Processing scripts (under Vector geometry) so that a Smoothing could be applied to overcome the crooked nature of rivers, only to find the result has not been combined into one river, rather simply copied to a new layer.
Style settings I have tried include: changing placement to Parallel or Horizontal and increasing the Label Overrun distance, only to find many more labels have been placed than necessary, and not running Curved along the river as desired. Reducing the text size doesn't always work, either, especially at the scale that I need (these maps are going into a book).
If it were possible to dynamically fix this using Geometry Generator, I am at a loss as to what sequence of functions to use.
Only a select few rivers are to be labeled, so overlap with other features, or layers, is not a problem.
The Details:
Map Scale: 1:5,000,000
Layer Styling (all other options remain as default)
Text
    Size: 10 points
Formatting
    Spacing
        letter: 0.6563
        word: 0.2155
Buffer
    Size: 1.25 points
Placement
    General Settings
        Mode: Curved
        Allowed positions: Above line, Below line
        Distance: 1.0 mm
    Repeating Labels
        Distance: No Repeat
    Label Overrun
        Overrun distance: 4.0 mm
    Maximum angle between curved characters
        inside: 29.0
        outside: 35.0
    Obstacles
        Features act as obstacles
Rendering
    Overlapping labels
        Mode: Never Overlap
    Feature options
        Merge connected lines to avoid duplicate labels

Data Source:
National Hydrography Dataset (NHD)
https://www.usgs.gov/national-hydrography/access-national-hydrography-products
The link at Download the NHD by the Entire Nation will take you here:
https://prd-tnm.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html?prefix=StagedProducts/Hydrography/NHD/National/
Download either version and find the Network Flowline data table. Be careful, the dataset is huge (multiple gigabytes). After importing into PostgreSQL/PostGIS, I have copied a greatly-filtered selection to a much smaller table to speed up rendering.
Software used
QGIS 3.36.2-Maidenhead
PostgreSQL 16 with PostGIS 3
KDE Plasma 5.27.5
Debian 12 (bookworm)


Have you tried checking the group by name box?

Where am I to find this "Group By Name" box?

Dynamic options are more elegant, but have the disadvantage that every time you zoom/pan, the rendering of the image generates a huge workload to comply with the settings. I propose a semi-automatic option, where you create simplified, smoothed auxiliary lines representing the whole river. For a cartographic solution, this is probably more practicable.

Use network tool shortest path to create a single part, one feature line from the source of the river to its mouth. See here for details: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/444603/88814

Label this line. Change settings like Maximum angle.

Simplify and smooth the line. You can do this just for the labels, without creating a new line, by checking the Geometry Generator box in Layer styling -> Placement tab. Adjust the values to see in realtime how the labels change.


Of course, the settings also depend on zoom-level, so either make optimal settings for the zoom-level you want to use or make scale-dependent labels.
Blue: original multipart linestring for Mississippi river; red (just for visualization): singlepart linestring based on shortest path, simplified and smoothed with Geometry generator:

Zoomed in and using other settings:


And labels with postion on line to label inside the waterbody when zoomed in:


You need to group together the features that share the same label. This option is called "Merge connected lines to avoid duplicate labels" and is on the rendering tab of the label styling tab.

